# How to get files count using creation date time older then 90 days in Windows PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have requirement to get files count older then 90days from entire directory which contains multiple sub-folders.
I tried below script but no luck.

```
dir Z:\EDI\ |
    ? {$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) -and !$_.PsIsContainer} |
    group {$_.CreationTime.ToShortDateString()} |
    select Name, Count
```

Comment: what version of powershell are you using? also, you may want to fix your code formatting ... some of the characters seem to be missing. ///// plus, i think you have your comparison reversed - try `-le` instead of `-ge`

Comment: Hi I am executing command in OS windows 10 using with Windows powershell ISE window

Comment: thank you for that info. i think your problem is that you have the date test reversed. try using `-le` instead of `-ge`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response i got output listing out date wise, is there any possible to get along with above result will get total of files count in last line

Comment: save it in a Variable and use `.count`

Comment: And its working for only specify folder not working for all sub-folders 
for example listing files count under Z:\EDI\Input\    only
not working for Z:\EDI\   This directory having multiple subfolders like input , output,error etc. any change required in above command please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a somewhat different way to get the info. [*grin*]

it uses date math to get the age in days and compares that to the max allowed. then it puts that in a custom object that can be used later for getting details.

```
$MaxAgeInDays = 90
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP

$TooOldFileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object {($Today - $_.CreationTime).Days -ge $MaxAgeInDays} |
    Sort-Object CreationTime |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AgeInDays = ($Today - $_.CreationTime).Days
            FileName = $_.FullName
            }
        }

$OldestFile = $TooOldFileList |
    Select-Object -First 1

''
'Max allowed age in days = {0, 5}' -f $MaxAgeInDays
'Number of too-old files = {0, 5}' -f $TooOldFileList.Count
'Oldest file age in days = {0, 5}' -f $OldestFile.AgeInDays
'Oldest file name        = {0}' -f $OldestFile.FileName
```

output ...

```
Max allowed age in days =    90
Number of too-old files =   296
Oldest file age in days =  1136
Oldest file name        = C:\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you its working successfully Can we add delete command in above command please let me know shall i use   "$_delete().$TooOldFileList

Comment: @VenkateshwarDiddi - you are most welcome! ///// you can pipe the collection to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet to get rid of them all. i recommend you use the `-WhatIf` parameter to let you see what it would do _before_ you run it for real, tho. [*grin*]

Comment: @VenkateshwarDiddi - not quite. [*grin*] once you have the collection, you can simply pipe that to the remove item cmdlet. something like this ... `$TooOldFilesList | Remove-Item -WhatIf` to remove all the files in the collection.

Comment: I tried above command but throwing error 

Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:17 char:19
+ $TooOldFilesList |Remove-Item -WhatIf
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: @VenkateshwarDiddi - run the script i posted. then - in the same session - enter just the collection variable `$TooOldFIlesList` on a line by itself to see if it contains anything. the msg you list seems to be saying that the collection is empty.

Comment: @VenkateshwarDiddi Change this `FileName = $_.FullName` to `Path = $_.FullName` and next `'Oldest file name        = {0}' -f $OldestFile.FileName` into `'Oldest file name        = {0}' -f $OldestFile.Path`. Then the objects will have a `Path` property the `Remove-Item` cmdlet is looking for.